# Displaying Title attribute message using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am working out a small registration form whereby I have several input fields.  For validation procedures, I was trying to add a single javascript function that can help me to validate input data in one textbox, using the onchange concept, as I press TAB to move to the next. The aim is that as soon I enter wrong data and press TAB, the message in the Title attribute should appear .But so far, I am not succeeding.   The javascript function is client side. Below are snippet codes.  Can someone please help me out.

```js
function myFunction(title) {
     var at = title.value;
     alert(at);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Firstname"  ValidationExpression=[a-zA-Z] title="Firstname not correct" onchange="myFunction(this.title)">
<input type="text" name="telno" ValidationExpression=[0-9]{7} title="Tel num not correct" onchange="myFunction(this.title)">
<input type="text" name="Address" ValidationExpression=[a-zA-Z0-9] title="Address not correct"  onchange="myFunction(this.title)">
```

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onchange` attribute is already passing the title attribute `myFunction(this.title)`, this is right syntax.

```js
function myFunction(title) {
     var at = title;
     alert(at);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Firstname"  ValidationExpression=[a-zA-Z] title="Firstname not correct" onchange="myFunction(this.title)">
<input type="text" name="telno" ValidationExpression=[0-9]{7} title="Tel num not correct" onchange="myFunction(this.title)">
<input type="text" name="Address" ValidationExpression=[a-zA-Z0-9] title="Address not correct"  onchange="myFunction(this.title)">
```

Comment: Hello Adam, in fact everytime I am entering value to the textboxes I am getting the title messages even when I am entering correct data.  Is there any modification I have to make with the javascript?